# vtkFiltering.dll is missing

Tags: visual-c++, dll

I compiled VTK using CMake and Visual Studio C++.
I followed these instructions:
http://www.divms.uiowa.edu/~cwyman/classes/common/howto/winVTK.html

I used an existing code I found online to test out if everything works right.
http://www.vtk.org/VTK/help/examplecode.html

When I clicked debug... I got the following system error pop up.
"The program can't start because vtkFiltering.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this program."

I tried doing those steps again and I still got the same thing come up.

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows the linker isn't very flexible, you will need to either add the path to the directory containing the VTK DLLs to your PATH environment variable, or put the executable in the same directory as the DLLs. This is a general issue with Windows, and not really all that specific to VTK. You could also build VTK static, and then simply statically link.

Comment: I did what you said but I'm still having that problem. I added the bin folder containing the dlls and I get that window with missing dlls error. I checked and that particular dll does exist in that directory.